# Change default folder for Chrome bookmarks

Tags: chrome-for-android

Every time I add a bookmark in Chrome, it saves it to "Mobile bookmarks". I now have to press "Edit" and change the folder to "Bookmarks bar". I'm sure that Chrome previously saved to the last folder that was saved to. Is there a way to default to Bookmarks bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Chrome now does this - not sure if something was fixed recently! Cannot Reproduce.